# How do I grab multiple values in regex?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, grafana

I'm trying to filter out 3 sensu check values for templating.

I'm using Elasticsearch as a datasource

```
Query: {"find": "terms","field":"check_name.keyword"}

Regex: /.*_error_100.*|.*_error_200.*|.*_error_300.*/
```

Is my regex wrong?

Thank you 
Devon

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? Your current regex looks fine. It can be re-written as `.*_error_[123]00.*` but are you sure you are using the pattern in the right place? Are `/` around the pattern necessary? What is the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1):

> Matching everything like `.*` is very slow as well as using lookaround
>   regular expressions.

To query some field by regex (exemplary query):

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "somefield": "_error_[123]00"
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax

Comment: *Lucene’s patterns are always anchored. The pattern provided must match the entire string.* You **must** use `.*_error_[123]00.*` in Lucene regex patterns to match a field that *contains* a pattern.

Comment: Perfect thank you!!! Still learning regex and lucene querying.. If I can, I would like to ask one more question (same subject matter).. If I want to do the same for host names, would this work `ip-10-1-[80-96]-.*` Trying to get multiple subnets on this one (ip is host name).